# Why is the Taylor series $\ln(1-2x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{(-2x)^k}{k} $ incorrect?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

We know that: $$\ln(1+x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^k}{k} $$
Can we replace $x$ by $-2x$ and get:
$$\ln(1-2x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{(-2x)^k}{k} $$
this?

Comment: as long as $|x| <\frac{1}{2}$ you are good.

Comment: Now you can simplify $(-2x)^k$.

Comment: What makes you think it is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can use the root test to find the [interval of convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence).

Answer (score 0):

We have to be restrictive to the radius of convergence

For example

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k\geq 0}x^k$$

Only converges for $|x|<1$ , which has the same radius as

$$\frac{1}{1+x} = \sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k x^k$$

By integrating we obtain

$$\log(1+x)= \sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k \frac{x^{k+1}}{1+k}$$

which onverges for $-1<x\leq 1$

For any composed function $f(x)$ we have to satisfy $|f(x)|<1$ . On the circle $|f(x)|=1$ the function might or might not converge .

Comment: Yes. It doesn't converge for $x=-1$